# SWT - PrintDialog Just to get the local printers and not print

Tags: swt, printdialog

Is it possible to use SWT PrintDialog just to display the local printers and then return the selected printer value?

I have a print class that works well for me.  I pass in the following variables to the class.

String filePath
String printerName
String jobName

I call the Print class from my GUI class the following way.

```
new AplotPdfPrintLocal().printPDF("c:\\Temp\\test.pdf", "\\\\PrintServer\\MyPrinter","PDF Print Job");
```

Right now the call is passing in the default printer.

Before the above call, I would be great to open a local printer dialog (Like PrintDialog).
Be able to select a local printer, then call my Print Class with the selected printer value. I would prefer to have my Print Class preform the printing action instead of PrintDialog.

I was thinking that when the OK button is pressed in the PrintDialog, we go do something like the following pseudo code

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
   new AplotPdfPrintLocal().printPDF("c:\\Temp\\test.pdf", "SelectedPrinterValue","PDF Print Job");
}
```

Is this possible?
Is there a better way to preform this action?

I know there is a way to look up the local printers (PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices()). 
But I really don't want to have to write a new dialog around it, I would rather use a pre written existing Dialog like PrintDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrintDialog` provides you native printing options. If you do not want to use `PrintDialog` then you end up setting all printing options ( `PrintData` and other paper option..etc that you see in PrintDialog).

Define `PrintData` with print options and  create Printer(printerdata) and start printing job.